# Cannot see characters when I use Font Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to use the font awesome plugin. But I cannot see the characters. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>THIS IS IT</h1>
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
</body>
</html
```

Is this just me or has anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: If you are running this locally, add `http:` before the preceding `//`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with http:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Turns out all it needed was an http at the beginning. Thank you.